# xls (excel) to charts

Tags: jquery, xml, excel, charts, xls

I have a [excel file](http://www.postennorden.com/Global/Document/Om-Oss/IR/Financial-data/Q4%202010%20quarterly%20data.xls) (xls) and I want to show that data in charts on a web page.

I can save the file as a [xml document](http://files.patrikelfstrom.se/data.xml) in Excel but i don't now how to parse it.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "data.xml",
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function(xml){
            parseXml(xml);
        }
    });
});

function parseXml(xml)
{
    var xml = $(xml);
    var data = xml.find("Worksheet").children('table').children('row').children('Cell');
    console.log(data);
}
```

This works "kind of" but to get the right values is hard.

For example, if I want to get the Net Sales which looks like this in the xml document:

```
    <Row>
        <Cell ss:StyleID="s44">
            <Data ss:Type="String">Net sales</Data>
        </Cell>
        <Cell ss:StyleID="s45">
            <Data ss:Type="Number">11779.0</Data>
        </Cell>
        <Cell ss:StyleID="s45">
            <Data ss:Type="Number">10996.0</Data>
        </Cell>
        <Cell ss:StyleID="s46"/>
        <Cell ss:StyleID="s45">
            <Data ss:Type="Number">10222.0</Data>
        </Cell>
        <Cell ss:StyleID="s46"/>
        <Cell ss:StyleID="s45">
            <Data ss:Type="Number">11636.0</Data>
        </Cell>
        <Cell ss:StyleID="s45">
            <Data ss:Type="Number">10918.0</Data>
        </Cell>
        <Cell ss:StyleID="s42"/>
        <Cell ss:StyleID="s45">
            <Data ss:Type="Number">10231.0</Data>
        </Cell>
        <Cell ss:StyleID="s45">
            <Data ss:Type="Number">9649.0</Data>
        </Cell>
        <Cell ss:StyleID="s46"/>
        <Cell ss:StyleID="s45">
            <Data ss:Type="Number">10871.0</Data>
        </Cell>
    </Row>
```

Comment: Please check my [updated test case](http://jsfiddle.net/mekwall/92sGk/)!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since jQuery 1.5, there's built-in support for parsing an XML string to a jQuery object. Just use [`jQuery.parseXML`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/) and then you can query the resulting jQuery object just as if it were a DOM.

Due to the same origin policy (see [HTTP access control on MDC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/http_access_control)) I was prevented from doing a cross-browser GET, so I had to copy the the source code from your XML file and put it in a textarea.

Could be be that any escaping you had in there was lost because I am getting a parse error. The attribute `ss:Format` contains an invalid value:

```
_-* #,##0.00\ _k_r_-;\-* #,##0.00\ _k_r_-;_-* &quot;-&quot;??\ _k_r_-;_-@_-
```

I removed this value, and it worked like a charm! See my [test case on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mekwall/92sGk/).

Comment: Nice, but I need to show it as a chart. Like this one here : http://www.postennorden.com/en/About-Us/Investor-Relations/Financial-Data/

Comment: @Patrik, Check the test case again. Fooled around with [gChart](http://keith-wood.name/gChart.html) and managed to get it to look as you wanted ;)

Comment: Sorry I havent replied. Got caught up in other stuff. That is very nice work. Thanks man!

Comment: @Patrik, no problemo. I'm happy I could help!